# Kill fbi frame buffer process, after x time

Tags: unix, timer, sh, wait, framebuffer

I have a problem  with a sh script.

I am using a raspberry, and want in my script to display with fbi frame buffer an image for 10 seconds. After these 10 seconds I want my script to run other sequential commands.

I wrote:

```
[...]
if[...]
fbi --noverbose $MEDIAFILE
MYPID=pgrep fbi
echo "[$MYPID] this is MY PID - and now i kill it!!!"
[...]
```

but my script stops itself in the first line (`fbi --noverbose...`) and I can't kill it in the next line :(.

I can't execute the command in background because I need to see the image...

any idea? thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is to not show anymore after a certain amount of seconds, you can also add the command line options "-t secs" and "-1". "-t secs" is used for slideshows and is the time after which the next image is shown and "-1" means that the slideshow wont loop.
In your case:

```
fbi --noverbose -t 10 -1 $MEDIAFILE
```

This shows the image for ten seconds and then the fbi command finishes. No need to kill the process.

Answer (score 2):

If fbi can't be run in the background, put your kill command in the background. To make it happen after a delay, use a subshell that sleeps first, then runs the kill command. The script would look something like this:

```
( sleep 10 ; kill $(pgrep fbi) ) &
fbi somefile
```

Comment: Greatttt !! i'm a stupid!!! i lost a day with this... i'll try but i'm sure that is the solution! thank you! :D